# How should implement multi-thread in single-threaded Operating system using java?

Tags: java, operating-system

How should implement multi-thread in single-threaded Operating system using java?

Java supports "Multi-threading".Is there is any way run the multiple threads (Implementing multi threading) using java in a Single-threaded Operating system (That is the operating system does not support for multi-threading).

Comment: Early JVM's used to do this.  It was called "green threads" and worked reasonably well, except when it didn't. :-)  It had problems with things that resembled files but were actually devices that could block, like named pipes.

Comment: What single-threaded operating system are you using?

Comment: Hi,  Mike Clark  the question my java interview question.So i post here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can do this, but nevertheless they will processed (within the CPU) one after another...

Answer (score 2):

Only if the Java implementation lets you. Early JVMs had user-space threads, but they moved to OS threads some time ago. If you are on a single-threaded OS, I suppose it's possible the JVM you are using still has user-space threading.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is possible to do what you have metioned.Because the java application is running in the JVM.So the JVM will handle the multi-threading issues for you. But still the operating system is sigle-thread,  the efficiency of your appliation will stay the same.